# Why reduce(getattr()) works, but reduce(hasattr()) doesn't?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can get functools.reduce() to work with getattr(), but I can't get it to work with hasattr().  Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
import functools

# Quick and dirty nested instances    
mt_class = type('mt_class', (object,), {})
this = mt_class()
setattr(this, 'that', mt_class())
setattr(this.that, 'the_other', mt_class())
setattr(this.that.the_other, 'my_str', "howdy!")
```

```
In [6]: functools.reduce(getattr, ['that', 'the_other'], this)
Out[6]: <__main__.mt_class at 0x88784cc>

In [7]: functools.reduce(getattr, ['that', 'the_other'], this).my_str 
Out[7]: 'howdy!'
```

```
In [8]: functools.reduce(hasattr, ['that', 'the_other'], this)
Out[8]: False
```

**Clarification:**
Yes, I expect that reduce(hasattr()) would return True.

```
In [13]: hasattr(this.that.the_other, 'my_str')
Out[13]: True
```

Comment: Why would it work the same? `hasattr` doesn't do the same as `getattr`, regardless of `reduce`.

Comment: I assume he's expecting it to return true.

Comment: @delnan: According to the Python3 hasattr() docs: "[hasattr] is implemented by calling getattr(object, name) and seeing whether it raises an AttributeError or not."  To me, expecting it to act the same would seem reasonable.

Comment: It *uses* `getattr`, but it's not identical to it: It returns *whether* there is such an attribute, not what its current value is.

Comment: @delnan: Ok, I see what you're getting at.  As in J.F.Sebastian's answer, getattr() is returning a reference to the object.  hasattr() is returning True/False.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`result = reduce(getattr, ['attr_of_this', 'attr_of_attr_of_this'], this)` is equivalent to:

```
attr_of_this = getattr(this, 'attr_of_this')
result = getattr(attr_of_this, 'attr_of_attr_of_this')
```

and `reduce(hasattr, ['attr_of_this', 'attr_of_attr_of_this'], this)` is equivalent to:

```
true_or_false = hasattr(this, 'attr_of_this')
always_false_for_nonbool_attr = hasattr(true_of_false, 'attr_of_attr_of_this')
```

`bool()` has no `attr_of_attr_of_this` therefore the result is `False`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I suspected.  Oh, well.  Thanks!